# Pass variable from rails application to node package

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application that uses a node package. I would like to be able to dynamically set a value in the configuration of the node package through setting an environment variable when I run the rails server. So ideally it would look something like this.

`MY_ENV_NUMBER=1 rails s`

and then in the config file of my node app I could do something like

`myEnvNumber: process.env.MY_ENV_NUMBER`

The node package is a dependency in the rails app. I'm not sure if there if there would be a better way to do this or not but any way to pass params from the rails app to the node package on startup would be great.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you are using Rails, node is only used to build assets. After the build process is over, node no longer runs.

All the JavaScript your wrote in app/javascript/packs/*.js in run in the browser,
not in node.  The `process` objects and `process.env` do not exist in the browser.

Maybe what you want to achive can be done is some other way?
For example you could write the value of your variable to the dom in some way, and then have JavaScript read it from there?

For example in application.html.erb:

```
<input type="hidden" id="MY_ENV_NUMBER" value="<%= ENV['MY_ENV_NUMBER'] %>">
```

Now this hidden field is available in every page of your app

Comment: That's a really good idea, I'm gonna give it a shot. Thank you!